# Can a recursive function be defined nowhere?

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

I'm trying to show that a given function isn't recursive, so I assumed that it was recursive and composed it with a known recursive function to get back a function that is nowhere defined. However, I'm uncertain whether this is sufficient to conclude that the composition isn't recursive.

Comment: Sure, the function that is defined nowhere is recursive. It can be implemented by looping forever regardless of input.

Comment: Hilarious. Related to questions about functions on the empty set, and such. :)

Comment: Do you mean recursively computable?

Comment: @Couchy "recursive function" is one of the correct terms by itself (there are sadly *many* synonymous terms for this notion).

Comment: No it's not sufficient. Basically the only way of showing something is not recursive is to reduce it to the halting problem.

Comment: @Couchy That's not strictly true (and actually you mean "reduce the halting problem to it") - while the halting problem does seem to be the simplest *natural* noncomputable set, there are noncomputable sets strictly weaker than, or even incomparable to, the halting problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a somewhat unfortunate terminological issue here: Most books require recursive functions to be total.

To be specific, let's look at functions from natural numbers to natural numbers.

$\bullet$ A *partial function* is a function $\phi\colon A\to\mathbb N,$ where $A$ can be any subset of $\mathbb N.$

$\bullet$ A *partial recursive function* is a partial function $\phi$ that can be computed by some Turing machine; the Turing machine, when applied to some input $n,$ must halt iff $n$ is in the domain of $\phi$ (and, in that case, the Turing machine must compute the right answer, $\phi(n)$).

$\bullet$ A *total function* is a partial function whose domain is all of $\mathbb N.$

$\bullet$ A *recursive function* is a partial recursive function which happens to be total (that is, defined on all of $\mathbb N.$)

So, with these standard definitions, a recursive function has to be total.

Now, it looks like OP is actually using "recursive" to mean what's usually called "partial recursive."  If that's so, then the method proposed will *not* work, since the empty function is a perfectly good partial recursive function.

If, in fact, OP did mean the standard definition of "recursive function", then the method proposed would be correct, since the empty function is not a recursive function (because it's not total).  [But it seems doubtful to me that this method would be useful in practice, which is why I suspect that this isn't actually what OP meant.  In a case where this method would seem to be applicable, it would probably be easier just to prove directly that the function in question wasn't total.]

Comment: Just a small note: the empty function is total if you are considering functions $f : \emptyset \rightarrow A$.  It's a little hard to tell exactly the context the OP is discussing and this likely not very helpful to them.  But it an important fact in some contexts.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic What you wrote (about functions with empty domain) is technically true, but: "...an important fact in some contexts"?  I'm not aware of any context where it's important (or where it even comes up at all).

Comment: As one example $\emptyset$ is the initial object in **Set** because there is a total function from the empty set to every other set.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the nowhere defined function is recursive. (As spaceisdarkgreen explained in the comments: consider the program that loops forever regardless of input.)

To illustrate the problem with your reasoning in another way: Let $f$ be any function which is not total. Pick a natural number $n$ such that $f(n)$ is not defined. Compose $f$ with the constant function $c(x)=n$. The resulting function $f(c(x))$ is nowhere defined. Can we conclude that $f$ is not recursive?